# Keeping form data on submission -> array data

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

In my form im using JavaScript to add extra rows to my form
works great but if the form is submitted incorrectly it refreshes with the warning message (form shown below) but removes all the added textboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowNum = 0;

    function addRow(frm) {
        rowNum++;

        var row = '<div id="rowNum' + rowNum + '"><div class="dateinput">   <input id="theDate[]" style="width:100px;" value="<? echo date(" d/m/Y "); ?>" name="theDate[]" type="text"></div><div class="sportinput"><select style="width:100px;" id="Sport[]" name="Sport[]"><option>Horse Racing</option><option>Football</option><option>Greyhounds</option><option>NFL</option></select></div><div class="pickinput"><input style="width:250px;" id="Pick[]" name="Pick[]" type="text"></div><div class="bookieinput"><select style="width:100px;" id="Bookie[]" name="Bookie[]"><option>Bet365</option><option>Betfred</option><option>BetVictor</option><option>Boylesports</option><option>Bwin</option><option>Centrebet</option><option>Coral</option><option>Ladbrokes</option><option>Paddy Power</option><option>Pinnacle Sports</option><option>SBOBET</option><option>Sky Bet</option><option>Stan James</option><option>unibet</option><option>William Hill</option></select></div><div class="oddsinput"><input id="Odds[]" name="Odds[]" size="3" type="text"></div><div class="backorlayinput"><select id="BackorLay[]" name="BackorLay[]"><option>Back</option><option>Lay</option></select></div><div class="stakeinput"><input id="Stake[]" name="Stake[]" size="3" type="text">E/W<input name="EW[]" ID="EW[]" value="EW" type="checkbox" /></div><div class="cominput"><select id="Com[]" name="Com[]"><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></div><div class="outcomeinput"><select id="Outcome[]" name="Outcome[]"><option>Unknown</option><option>Win</option><option>Loss</option><option>P</option><option>E/W Win</option><option>Void</option></select></div><div class="placeinput"><select id="PlaceDiv[]" name="PlaceDiv[]"><option>5</option><option>4</option></select></div><div class="addrowinput"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"></div><br /></div>';


        jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);

        frm.add_qty.value = '';
        frm.add_name.value = '';
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
        jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Is it possible that if the form is submitted with errors then the rows are still displayed with the values in it?

```
<form method="post">
    <center>
    <style>
.dateinput {
   width:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
} 
        .sportinput {
   width:100px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
                .bookieinput {
   width:100px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
                .pickinput {
   width:250px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
                    .oddsinput {
 width:50px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
                    .backorlayinput {
 width:100px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
                    .stakeinput {
 width:110px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
                    .cominput {
 width:100px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
        .outcomeinput {
 width:100px;
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
} 
.placeinput {
 width:70px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
        }
        .addrowinput {
 width:70px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
echo $errorMessage; ?>
    <div class="dateinput">
         Date
    </div>
    <div class="sportinput">
         Sport
    </div>
    <div class="pickinput">
         Pick
    </div>
    <div class="bookieinput">
         Bookie
    </div>
    <div class="oddsinput">
         Odds
    </div>
    <div class="backorlayinput">
         Back or Lay
    </div>
    <div class="stakeinput">
         Stake
    </div>
    <div class="cominput">
         Comm (%)
    </div>
    <div class="outcomeinput">
         Outcome
    </div>
    <div class="placeinput">
         Palce Div
    </div>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <div class="dateinput">
            <input id="theDate[]" style="width:100px;" value="<?php echo date(" d/m/y "); ?>" name="theDate[]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="sportinput">
            <select style="width:100px;" id="Sport[]" name="Sport[]">
                <option>Horse Racing</option>
                <option>Football</option>
                <option>Greyhounds</option>
                <option>NFL</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="pickinput">
            <input style="width:250px;" id="Pick[]" name="Pick[]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="bookieinput">
            <select style="width:100px;" id="Bookie[]" name="Bookie[]">
                <option>Bet365</option>
                <option>Betfred</option>
                <option>BetVictor</option>
                <option>Boylesports</option>
                <option>Bwin</option>
                <option>Centrebet</option>
                <option>Coral</option>
                <option>Ladbrokes</option>
                <option>Paddy Power</option>
                <option>Pinnacle Sports</option>
                <option>SBOBET</option>
                <option>Sky Bet</option>
                <option>Stan James</option>
                <option>unibet</option>
                <option>William Hill</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="oddsinput">
            <input id="Odds[]" name="Odds[]" size="3" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="backorlayinput">
            <select id="BackorLay[]" name="BackorLay[]">
                <option>Back</option>
                <option>Lay</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="stakeinput">
            <input id="Stake[]" name="Stake[]" size="3" type="text">E/W<input name="EW[]" id="EW[]" value="EW" type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <div class="cominput">
            <select id="Com[]" name="Com[]">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="outcomeinput">
            <select id="Outcome[]" name="Outcome[]">
                <option>Unknown</option>
                <option>Win</option>
                <option>Loss</option>
                <option>P</option>
                <option>E/W Win</option>
                <option>Void</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="placeinput">
            <select id="PlaceDiv[]" name="PlaceDiv[]">
                <option>5</option>
                <option>4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="addrowinput">
            <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row"/>
        </div>
    </p>
    <div id="itemRows">
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save Changes">
    </p>
    </center>
</form>
```

Comment: If you use ajax to submit the form, you can keep the added elements.

Comment: HTTP is stateless. So it won't remember the additional text boxes added by a manual event. Use your PHP code to determine the number of new text boxes and add them correspondingly.

Comment: how would i determine the boxes???

Comment: Determine the size of theDate[] after submission (at your PHP end). When you redirect to the same page after validation in PHP, create as many textboxes.